# Where do I install Apache2 in my existing Django Project

Tags: django, apache, web

I have an existing Django project running on uWSGI, and I want to install Apache2 to act as the web server.

I found instructions online on how to do the installation - see link below.

https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-setup-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod-wsgi-on-ubuntu

One thing the instructions does not mention is where do I run the installation. Do I run the installation in /root? Or somewhere else.

Also, any feedback on the online instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands used to install Apache can be run from any directory.  Those command will install pieces of it to various paths in your system and not into the current directory:

- `/var/log/apache2`
- `/etc/apache2`
- `/var/lib/apache2`
- `/usr/share/doc/`
- `/usr/share/apache2`